# Behrend's construction vs. Triangle removal lemma

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, additive-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory, arithmetic-progression

I was reading Zhao's book ["Graph theory and additive combinatorics"](https://yufeizhao.com/gtacbook/gtacbook.pdf) and on page 71 I came across Remark 2.5.4 which I'd like to understand.

> **Theorem 2.3.1** (Triangle removal lemma) For all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$  such that any graph on $n$ vertices with fewer than
> $\delta n^3$ triangles can be made triangle-free by removing fewer
> than $\varepsilon n^2$ edges.
>
> **Theorem 2.5.1** (Behrend's construction) For sufficiently large $n$, there exists a $3$-AP-free $A\subseteq [n]$ with $\lvert A\rvert\geq ne^{-C\sqrt{\log n}}$,
> where $C>0$ is absolute constant.
>
> One can show that Behrend's construction implies the following
> **Corollary 2.5.2** (lower bound for the diamond-free lemma). For sufficiently large $n$, there is some $n$-vertex graph with at least
> $n^2e^{-C\sqrt{\log n}}$ edges where every edge lies on a unique
> triangle. Here $C$ is some absolute constant.

And the next paragraph is a bit unclear.

The same graph construction also shows that in the triangle removal lemma, one cannot take $\delta=e^{-c(\log(1/\varepsilon))^2}$ if $c>0$ is too small. Why can't we take such $\delta$? Of course, I'll provide what I've done so far but I cannot find any contradiction in my reasoning.

Assume that we can take such $\delta$, then we have the following: Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given, then any $n$-vertex graph with $\leq e^{-C_1(\log (1/\varepsilon))^2}n^3$
triangles can be made triangle-free by removing $\leq \varepsilon n^2$ edges.

By corollary, we know that for sufficiently large $n$, one can construct an $n$-vertex graph $G$ such that $\lvert E(G)\rvert\geq n^2e^{-C_2\sqrt{\log n}}$  ($C_2>0$) and each edge lies on a unique triangle. Let $n\geq e^{C_1(\log (1/\varepsilon))^2}$ and let $G$ be such an $n$-vertex graph. Then $$\#\text{triangles in $G$}=\lvert E(G)\rvert/3\leq n^2\leq e^{-C_1(\log (1/\varepsilon))^2}n^3.$$
Therefore, $G$ can be made triangle-free  by removing $\leq \varepsilon n^2$ edges. Also notice that this graph $G$ can be made triangle-free by removing exactly $\lvert E(G)\rvert/3\geq \frac{1}{3}n^2e^{-C_2\sqrt{\log n}}$ edges. Hence, $$\frac{1}{3}n^2e^{-C_2\sqrt{\log n}}\leq \varepsilon n^2 \iff \frac{1}{3e^{C_2\sqrt{\log n}}}\leq \varepsilon.$$

So where is the contradiction?

Comment: You say "the next paragraph".  The next paragraph of what?  If you are quoting from a paper, then please indicate the paper.

Comment: @LSpice, It is from the book. Edited!

Comment: For $C_1$ (and $\varepsilon$) small enough, one can choose $n$ so that $n \geq e^{C_1(\log(1/\varepsilon))^2}$ and $\frac{1}{3e^{C_2\sqrt{\log n}}} > \varepsilon$, giving the desired contradiction.

Comment: @TerryTao, sorry I meant this: You can always choose $n$ in such a way that the first inequality holds. But I am not sure about the second one since $\frac{1}{3e^{C_2\sqrt{\log n}}}\to 0$ and it could be there is no such $n$.

Comment: @TerryTao, dear Prof Tao, Pondering for a while on your hint I've realized that my previous comment is meaningless and this is what you meant probably: let $f(n)=\frac{1}{3e^{C_2\sqrt{\log n}}}$ and fix $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(N)<\varepsilon<f(N+1)$ for some large $N$ (not depending on $\varepsilon$, this $N$ comes from Corollary 2.5.2). Let $C_1>0$ be so small such that $e^{C_1(\log (1/\varepsilon))^2}<2$.

Comment: @TerryTao, Then taking $N+1$ and repeating my argument above we obtain that $\frac{1}{3e^{C_2\sqrt{\log (N+1)}}}\leq \varepsilon$ and this is contradiction since $f(N+1)>\varepsilon$. Does it make sense?

Comment: That's perhaps more convoluted than necessary, but is essentially correct.  It may be a good exercise for you to write up a complete argument (paying particular attention to the quantifiers and the dependencies between parameters) and post it as an answer to this question.